# Что изучать: WinForms или WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Вот скажите, как это понимать, когда я только начал читать книги, мне писали "Начинайте с консольных приложений". Потом когда я прошёл этот курс, в другой книге уже начали говорить о WinForms, и сейчас я начал читать другую книгу, там автор вообще пишет:

> Зачем писать под WinForms, ведь её элементы почти не менялись за последние 10 лет, учите лучше WPF

Я сейчас вообще как ёжик в тумане. Что учить? На чём остановиться? Что ждёт дальше? Может быть, я поучу WPF, а в другой книге уже будут говорить о новом более красочном написании приложений? Можете помочь распутаться и всё расставить по полочкам... пожалуйста.

Comment: по-моему, это вполне нормальное явление вещей - технологии развиваются, главное для хорошего программиста, не знать на 100% какую-то одну технологию(хотя это желательно), а уметь быстро разбираться с новыми, иначе вы просто не сможете остаться в этой отрасли

Comment: wpf практичнее.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если Вас интересует программирование desktop-приложений под Windows, то лучше остановиться на WPF, так как:

- это просто самая новая технология на данный момент
- использует 3D-ускоритель для отрисовки интерфейса
- ну и готовых возможностей по "украшению" интерфейса здесь гораздо больше

Хотя, если Вы будете использовать WinForms, приложения будут также отлично работать, так что выбор за Вами.

Насчёт того что ждёт дальше, то до выхода [Windows 8](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8) нкаких изменений не планируется.  Но как обещают в Microsoft, после её выхода появится возможность разрабатывать интерфейс desktop-приложений используя HTML+CSS+JS.

Comment: ...и гемор с Metro UI

Answer (score 3):

Да, смотря что ты хочешь создавать.
WPF больше подходит для крутых компов, где стоит минимум XP, с .NET 3.0. Библиотека тяжелая, но в Windows Vista уже стоит по умолчанию.
Но за эти неудобства WPF дает хорошие преимущества почти во всем, но только на Windows.
WindowsForms проектировать можно и даже предпочтительнее, у него есть следующие преимущества над WPF (сколько помню, столько и напишу)

---

1. SDI и MDI приложения (хотя есть библиотеки для эмуляции)
2. легче организовывать интерфейс OpenGL, DirectX
3. Теоретически кроссплатформенно за счет наличия MONO Framework
4. GDI+ легче в обращении (но медленнее), чем накрученная render-система в WPF
5. Вопреки распространённому заблуждению, поддерживают и полупрозрачные окна

Comment: Хотя WindowsForms по-прежнему поддерживается, оно по-прежнему остаётся обёрткой над WinAPI. А куча приложений написанных на WinAPI - это якорь, не дающий развивать ОС. .NET смягчает проблемы переноса, но не устраняет их. Так что лучше всё-таки WPF =)
Преимущества:
1. Рисуется через Direct3D, графикой занимается видеокарта а не процессор. Прозрачность, трансформации работают предельно быстро.
2. Интерфейс с D3D не нужен, а для создания контекста OpenGL в таком окне достаточно просто создать контрол WindowsFormsHost, у которого ЕСТЬ hWnd и hDC.
3. Огромные возможности кастомизации.

Comment: Согласен на все 100%

Answer (score 1):

Если нужны более глобальные сведения по выводу любых изображений, мне кажется, надо изучать DirectX и OpenGL. Если же надо попроще, то тогда WPF. Рад, если помогу определиться.

Answer (score 1):

Лично я (правда, вместе с Microsoft) порекомендую приступать к изучению UWP, Universal Windows Platform. Microsoft усиленно (но, к сожалению, не слишком то эффективно) проталкивает эту технологию, и, судя по всему, будет проталкивать ее еще определенное время, пока в очередной раз не сменится top management.

Опять-таки, программирование для WPF и UWP имеет много общего, так, что освоив UWP, вы без особого труда сможете писать и стандартные Windows приложения, а не только совместимые с Microsoft Store.

Кроме того, умение программировать UWP приложения привлекательно еще в чисто практическом смысле: освоив это, вы сможете опубликовать свое приложение в магазине, и сделать его доступным (потенциально) сотням миллионов пользователей. Не факт, конечно, что ваше приложение будет пользоваться хоть каким-то успехом, но уж несколько сотен закачек получите по любому. А работа с реальным проектом, и реальной отдачей - это лучшая практика для начинающего программиста, на порядки полезнее выполнения "стандартных" упражнений из учебника, уж поверьте мне на слово!