# Не получается изменить значение Label при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть переменная "sila". Она выводится на лейбл в функции start_game(). Переменная изменяется посредством кнопок button1 и button2. Однако при запуске программы при нажатии на кнопке значение переменной в лэйбле не меняется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка.
Код:

```
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int a = 5;
    static public int sila = 5;
    static public int inta = 5;
    static public int lovk = 5;
    static public int magic = 5;

    private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start_game();
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.cat;
        textBox1.Text = "Очков доступно:" + a.ToString();
    }
    private void start_game() 
    {
        label6.Text = sila.ToString();
        label7.Text = inta.ToString();
        label8.Text = lovk.ToString();
        label9.Text = magic.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sila--;
        a--;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sila++;
        a--;
    }
```

Comment: ошибка в том, что ты не присваиваешь изменившееся значение в label

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [c# не работает вывод числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739688/c-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: связанный вопрос, который автор задавал ранее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739688/213987

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что Вы только присваиваете переменной значение, но `Label.Text` не обновляете.

Решение Вашей проблемы максимально простое (по аналогии с тем, что Вам дали в предыдущем Вашем вопросе):

Следует в методах `button_click` изменять значение переменной *Label*:

```
label6.Text = sila.ToString();
```

Так же следует поступать во **всех** местах, где происходит изменение **значения** элементов и нужно эти изменения отобразить в окне.

Кстати говоря, для того что Вы пишите (это же игра, правильно?) куда лучше подошел бы [*WPF*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) со своим механизмом [`binding'a`](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.php), который позволяет **привязывать** данные к вашем *View* и потом, при изменении значений данных - меняется и отображение их на экране.

Но, если *WPF* для Вас сложно - можете посмотреть в сторону шаблона [Observer](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

**UPD**

Если есть выбор между *WPF* и *WinForms*, то *WPF* **однозначно** будет актуальнее. Другой вопрос, что само по себе клиентское программирование (для десктопов) на C# куда менее актуально чем то же веб-программирование (аля Java EE (Spring), ASP .NET MVC, PHP).

[Разница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/83773/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-winforms-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-wpf) между *WPF* и *WinForms* состоит по большей части в разных подходах к программированию [*GUI*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) и архитектура приложения (естественно, еще есть очень много разных изменений и моментов).

Хорошим тоном программирования на *WinForms* считается программирование по архитектура [*MVC*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), а для *WPF* чуть ли не единственным правильным вариантом считается архитектура [*MVVM*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-ViewModel).

Построение *GUI* на *WPF* (в отличии от *WinForms*) происходит с использованием языка [*XAML*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAML). Это не так страшно, как может показаться на первый взгляд. *XAML* код позволяет "связывать" (binding) данные *C#* с элементами *View*, что очень удобно.

В основном, логика программы написанная с использованием *WinForms*, если Вы писали "думая о будущем", не сильно будет отличаться от логики *WPF*.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Во время перерыва уже осознал ошибку и сам понял, насколько же прост был ответ:) Пока изучаю forms, а чтобы процесс был интересным пишу игру.  Не подскажите, а в чём сложность wpf относительно forms?

Comment: И самое главное, что будет актуальнее для изучения? (если рассматривать будущую профессию программиста)

Comment: @Алексей обновил ответ